# Pasar variable JavaScript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

Buenas tardes compañeros, tengo un problema, espero me puedan apoyar, necesito pasar datos almacenados en una variable mediante JavaScript a PHP, como puedo hacer eso? se me ocurria lo siguiente pero veo que no se puede:

```
  <body>
    <script>
            var miVariable = "Hola Mundo";                    
    </script> 
<?php
$datos = "<script>miVariable</script>";
echo $datos;
?>
    </body>
```

De antemano muchas gracias a todos.

P. D. Uso Windows 7 y PHP 7.

Comment: mira esto: http://www.coderslexicon.com/the-basics-of-passing-values-from-javascript-to-php-and-back/

Comment: Windows 7 no tiene mucho que ver aqui :). Ya respondi

Comment: Esta pregunta ya se ha realizado en numerosas ocasiones en el sitio y tiene respuestas (AJAX, formularios, cookies,...). Deberías buscar e investigar esas soluciones e indicar si no te valen y por qué. Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mi solucion seria colocar tu valor en una caja de texto usando javascript y seguido de ello usar `POST` de php para tomar el valor.

**javascript_a_php.php**

```
<html>
<form action="tu_action.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="caja_valor" id="caja_valor" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>
</html>

<script>
let valor = 4;
document.getElementById("caja_valor").value = valor;
</script>
```

**tu_action.php**

```
<?php
$valor = $_POST["caja_valor"];
echo $valor; 
// el valor
?>
```

### Notas

1. El `ID` en un campo se usa para que `javascript` pueda acceder al elemento html, por ende a sus atributos.
2. El `NAME` se usa para que `PHP` pueda obtener los valores de los elementos html.
3. El código `JAVASCRIPT` ya esta de tu parte como cargar los valores, si
   automáticamente, con un botón, un evento cualquiera entre otros.
4. El código `PHP` se activara cuando hagas presiones el input del tipo submit.

Answer (score 2):

Hola prueba con este código mas simple

```
<script>var Var_JavaScript = 5;    // declaración de la variable </script>  
    <?php
        $var_PHP = "<script> document.writeln(Var_JavaScript); </script>"; // igualar el valor de la variable JavaScript a PHP 

    echo $var_PHP   // muestra el resultado 

    ?>
```

Espero que te sea util

Answer (score -4):

Yo lo haría así:

```
<?php
$captura='';
if(!isset($_GET['variable'])){
    $captura='No';
}
?>
<body onload="parametro(<?php echo $captura; ?>) ">

<script>
function parametro(captura){
    var miVariable = "Hola Mundo"; 
    if(captura=='No'){
        window.location="esta_pagina.php?variable=miVariable";
    }    
}                   
</script> 
<?php
    $datos = $_GET['variable'];
    echo $datos;
?>
</body>
```

Espero y te sirva.

Comment: Debes explicarlo

Comment: Hola Jelmo, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Deberías editarla para añadir más información: ¿qué hace el código compartido? ¿cómo resuelve el problema? Lee [answer] para más recomendaciones y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y ganar tu primera medalla). Saludos.