# Pasar variable de Javascript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript

**Tengo un problema, necesito usar la variable total , esta dentro de un script pero necesito usarla como si fuera un variable de php , como puedo pasarla? **

```
echo "var total=math.eval('sqrt(75 / 3) + det([[-1, 2], [3, 1]]) - sin(pi / 4)^2');  ";
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Por qué no calculas el total con PHP en vez de JS?

Comment: Aquí hay una pregunta bastante similar a la tuya [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175143/pasar-variable-javascript-a-php), espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: @Jonathan , como podría hacer eso con php?