# Como traer una Variable de una Pagina php a Otra

Tags: php, javascript, css

Buenas tardes Me podrian ayudar tengo la siguiente situación:

Tengo un select(adjunto codigo) el cual me esta enviando el valor seleccionado a una variable PHP la cual capturo sin ningun problema.

```
<select id="seleccionarA" name="seleccionarA">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccione:</option>
  <?php 
                        while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2))
                        {
                   ?>
  
  <option value="<?php echo ($datos['idturnos'])?>"> <?php echo $datos['turno']?></option>
  <?php
                        }
                    ?>
```

Captura de Variable:

```
<?php
function get( string $string ) {
    return ( isset($_GET[(string) $string]) )
        ? $_GET[(string) $string] : "";
}

$variablePHP = get("seleccionar");
echo $variablePHP;
```

codigo Javascript:

```
seleccionarA.onchange = () => {
    let valor = seleccionarA.value;
    let ruta = `archivo.php?seleccionar=${valor}`;

    fetch(ruta)
        .then(respuesta => respuesta.text())
        .then(data => {
            resultados.textContent = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch( error => {
            resultados.textContent = error;
        })
};
```

Lo que necesito es:
enviar esa variable capturada a mi archivo php principal para poder usarla, realizar consultas en base de datos y poder imprimirla en un input text sin ningun problema.

Agradezco a quine pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Desde dónde quieres enviar? En un link o en un formulario?

Comment: es un php que me captura la variable enviada desde Javascript pero no hace nada mas,

Comment: No veo Javascript en el código de la pregunta. Leo que todo funciona bien en php, entonces no entiendo si lo que quieres es pasar a javascript o viceversa?

Comment: ya agregue al codigo javascript, lo que necesito es traer la variable que me esta mandando el javascritp a php y llevarla a otro php que es mi pagina principal y poder usarla libremente.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Pasar variable JavaScript a PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175143/pasar-variable-javascript-a-php)

Comment: Entonces el título de tu pregunta es diferente a lo que quieres hacer. Ya hay respuesta sobre esta pregunta en el comentario anterior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pasar Variables de un php a otro lo que puedes usar es una variable global llamada $_SESSION.

```
// php donde tienes tu variable
$_SESSION['Nombre de la variable'] = valor a pasar;
//php donde quieres usarla
echo($_SESSION['Nombre de la variable']);
```

Comment: Ojo con la sintaxis es [`$_SESSION`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php) todo en mayúsculas

Comment: @Luis Garcia Lo implemente pero en la pagina donde quiero usarla me sale el siguiente error:    de esta manera la estoy volviendo Global   <?php
function get( string $string ) {
    return ( isset($_GET[(string) $string]) )
        ? $_GET[(string) $string] : "";
}

$variablePHP = get("seleccionar");
echo $variablePHP;

$_SESSION['seleccionar'] = $variablePHP;

Comment: $variablePHP=$_SESSION['seleccionar']; de esta forma la estoy llamando donde quiero usarala y me da este error Warning: Undefined array key "seleccionar"

Comment: Revisa bien tu codigo ya que la $variablePHP; en el primer comentario no ha de tener valor por ende la variable $_SESSION no se define (NULL)

Comment: Gracias @LuisGarcia pero si esta recibiendo valor, lo recibe de una funcion de Javascript con el evento OnChange y al impimirla aparce, pero necesito usarla en mi documento pricnpal para poder hacer unas validaciones.

Comment: @David E. Luna M me puedes ayudar por favor

Comment: @JAIMEPOLANCO pásame tu código para echarle un vistazo

Comment: @LuisGarcia ya lo logre muchas gracias, ahora tengo otro problema, si pudieras mirar mi pregunta mas actual te lo agradecería muchooo