# Mi formulario a veces me rebota cuando publico algo en producción

Tags: php, blog

He desarrollado un blog en PHP con código puro sin Framework ni CMC. Resulta que el sitio web esta en producción y cuando voy a publicar una entrada y tardo mucho tiempo escribiendo la entrada al darle al botón de publicar muchas veces este me rebota y me manda a la pagina de inicio y se pierde lo que ya había escrito y es muy frustrante.

Hace un año desarrolle un blog y lo subí a Internet con la misma compañía de hosting que el actual y me sucedía lo mismo, si tardo mucho tiempo escribiendo la estrada este me rebota lo que escribo y me manda a la pagina de inicio y se pierde todo lo que ya había escrito.

No tengo idea si esto sucede por el servidor o porque razón.

Comment: Por lo que cuentas afirmaría que es una configuración en el servidor. Pero con esos datos no puedo asegurar. Por otro lado puedes hacer que eso no suceda haciendo un autosave o una recarga de logs con algo de js

Comment: Me interesa mucho eso que acabas de mencionar, tienes algún enlace o video que me puedas pasar para hacer el autosave

Comment: Cuando digo "autosave" me refiero a que cada X tiempo/caracteres modificados se guarde la información. Yo este tipo de situacciones las salvo con [JS y o AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433756/js-ajax-php-post-return-responsetext) tambien tienen el [JS $.GET](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175143/pasar-variable-javascript-a-php/175149)